# Is it possible to extend the data device of an Thin Provision pool setted by device mapper?

Tags: linux, lvm, thin-provisioning, device-mapper

TL;DR :

How can I extend the Thin-Pool if I'm not using LVM but Device Mapper itself directly?

Detailed version:

As far as I know, 
when we create a thin-pool by `dmsetup`, we can set a low_water_mark;

once the watermark is reached, a dmevent will be sent and the guard-daemon could extend the pool right away.

However, I was unable to find the way to perform such the task in trivial way; and I have no clue how it could be achieved.

Furthermore,
I dig into `dm-thin.c` and find out there's a function named `maybe_resize_data_dev`,
 which will enlarge data device by `r = dm_pool_resize_data_dev(pool->pmd, data_size)` if the remaining space is not enough.

Yet at the meanwhile, Device Mapper itself prevent you from doing that by verifying the status of data device:

`if (le32_to_cpu(disk_super->data_block_size) != pmd->data_block_size) {
    /* Verify the data block size hasn't changed */
    if (le32_to_cpu(disk_super->data_block_size) != pmd->data_block_size) {
        DMERR("changing the data block size (from %u to %llu) is not supported",
              le32_to_cpu(disk_super->data_block_size),
              (unsigned long long)pmd->data_block_size);
        r = -EINVAL;
        goto bad_unlock_sblock;
    }`

which is patched in commit 9aec862 , titled `dm thin metadata: do not allow the data block size to change`.

*The codes are quoted out from `drivers/md/dm-thin.c` (ref-1) and `drivers/md/dm-thin-metadata.c` (ref-2)*

And What confuse me more is that I happened to know that it could be done if the pool is created by LVM utilities ; i.e. 
`lvextend -L+100M vg001/mythinpool`
(from the [Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/thinly_provisioned_volume_creation.html) published by Red Hat) , which makes me wonder how it is achieved to do so.

ref-1 : drivers/md/dm-thin.c#L3246-L3292

ref-2 : drivers/md/dm-thin-metadata.c#L617-L621

*Sorry, I cannot post more than two links because I'm too noob .*

Comment: What's the reason for not using LVM? It would take care of resizing for you (the dmeventd daemon using LVM specific plugins for resizing volumes, no DM-direct plugin) and keep track of volumes. One option is to try strace with LVM thin-pool, which will give you a clue how to extend DM device.